# Obtain product keys of client machines on Windows Server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

How can I obtain Windows product keys of all clients that are joined to domain (Windows Server 2008R2)? The fact is I can't find which computer is linked to one specific licence key that I have. Is there a way to make a list of client machines with their licence keys from Windows Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [VAMT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824953.aspx) from Microsoft.